# Django + VueJS3 app: remove the Hashtag(#) from url

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs3, django-settings, vue-router4

Here is a tricky situation. I'm working on a Django project on top of which VueJS CDN is used for one application's render.
It goes like [www.mywebsite.com/newapp](http://www.mywebsite.com/newapp) where the new app only is rendered with VueJS.

The linked are handled by Vue router on a basic configuration:

```
// Routess // 
let routes = [
    { 
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: home,
        meta: { scrollPos:  { top: 140, left: 0 },
        },
    },
    { 
        path: '/about',
        name: 'about',
        component: about, 
        meta: {
            scrollPos: { top: 140, left: 0 },
        }, 
    },
];

const scrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
        if (to.hash) {
            return { el: to.hash };
        }
        return to.meta?.scrollPos ||  { top: 140, left: 0 };
    };

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    scrollBehavior,
    routes,
});

const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },    
});

const vm = app.use(router).mount('#app');
```

So I get this url link with a hashtag:

`www.mywebsite.com/newapp/#/`

`www.mywebsite.com/newapp/#/about/`

on a nested component, It will just be like

When I use only router history like:

```
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    scrollBehavior,
    routes,
});
```

Then I get `www.mywebsite.com/home`

But I do need to have to static url.

It doesn't seemed to be a proper way to remove the hashtag (#) in the url.

I found a [configuration](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode) that is related to this specific case scenario but since I'm on Django + Vue CDN app, I don't know if and how this can be applied

Comment: Django router all html request to index.html?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by 'all html request to index.html'. 
Let's say there are many apps and 'newapp' is one of them.
There are many base-index.html files.

Comment: If you don't want use # you should router ~/vueApp/* to ~/vueApp/index.html, vue will control router in client

Comment: I made a bit of research on that and I have to admit, I still don't understand the like you'r making between the index.html file and ~/vueApp/*
The base_index.html file here is the one with the <script> tag and Vue CDN.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that I found for this is to use `createWebHistory()` and to recreate all the paths with the base url in it.

```
let routes = [
{ 
    path: '/newapp/',
    name: 'home',
    component: home,
    meta: { scrollPos:  { top: 140, left: 0 },
    },
},
{ 
    path: '/newapp/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: about, 
    meta: {
        scrollPos: { top: 140, left: 0 },
    }, 
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be something like

```
{ mode: `hash`}
```

Use `history` instead.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    scrollBehavior() {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    },
    ...
})
```